# Directory path in rails outside app directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path

I've just created a script ("script.rb") in my project "bin" directory. Inside this file I'm including my environment.rb file. It looks like this:

```
require /home/user/rails-project/config/environment.rb
```

The problem is that I need to be able to upload this file to the live server where the path of the environment.rb file will be totally different. So what I need is to get the config path dynamically. The problem is that the file is outside "app" (it's in "bin") so I'm not able to do this:

```
require "#{Rails.root}/config/environment.rb"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

On the server you should create a symlink for this. This is a very common practice for secret files (file with passwords) and the database.yml file.

on the server:
cd path/to/config/
ln -s path/to/environment.rb environment.rb